# When does ++ not produce the same results as +1?

Tags: c#, stack, increment

The following two C# code snippets produce different results (assuming the variable level is used both before and after the recursive call). Why?

```
public DoStuff(int level)
{
  // ...
  DoStuff(level++);
  // ...
}
```

,

```
public DoStuff(int level)
{
  // ...
  DoStuff(level+1);
  // ...
}
```

After reading some of the responses below I thought it would be worthwhile posting the stack traces for level++, ++level and level+1 to highlight how deceiving this problem is.

I've simplified them for this post. The recursive call sequence starts with DoStuff(1).

// level++

```
DoStuff(int level = 1)
DoStuff(int level = 2)
DoStuff(int level = 2)
DoStuff(int level = 2)
```

// ++level

```
DoStuff(int level = 4)
DoStuff(int level = 4)
DoStuff(int level = 3)
DoStuff(int level = 2)
```

// level+1

```
DoStuff(int level = 4)
DoStuff(int level = 3)
DoStuff(int level = 2)
DoStuff(int level = 1)
```

Comment: Great question and great answer! I've been using C++ for years and C# more recently, and I had no idea!

Comment: Your stack traces are wrong. level++ should be 1, 1, 1, 1; ++level should be 1, 2, 3, 4; and level + 1 should be 1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: Orion - the stack traces were taken directly from VS2008. I traced the function calls to four levels of recursion and did a cut and paste.

Comment: Ah.. I'm writing the stack traces with the last call being at the bottom, rather than at the top. I'm not looking at the values of level, but rather what value is being passed to each function. To properly evaluate the stack, you should put a breakpoint at the first line of the function.

Answer (score 44):

To clarify all the other responses:

+++++++++++++++++++++

```
DoStuff(a++);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
DoStuff(a);
a = a + 1;
```

+++++++++++++++++++++

```
DoStuff(++a);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
a = a + 1;
DoStuff(a);
```

+++++++++++++++++++++

```
DoStuff(a + 1);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
b = a + 1;
DoStuff(b);
```

+++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: Except your example for `DoStuff(a++)` is wrong. It should be:

    int temp = a;
    a = a + 1;
    DoStuff(temp);

Comment: Parameters are never evaluated after the function call to which they belong. Compiler optimizations may change the order of calls, but that goes beyond this simple example. Any number of things may be re-organized.

Comment: a++ creates a temporary variable before the call with the old value and increments straight away, not an increment afterwards. In certain situations, the difference is very pronounced.

Comment: is the first example really right? in C++, at least your example is wrong. evaluations of arguments are complete before the call is made (there is a sequence point just before the call is made). If that is true for C# too, then your example (the first one) is wrong.

Comment: If a for example is a member variable and DoStuff accesses it, it will find the old value using your example, while (in C++ at least) it will find the new value (although the parameter, of course, contains the old value) in real code.

Comment: This is probably an example of where common knowledge is wrong because it seems despite the very pronounced wrongness of this answer, it's still by and far the most up-voted answer. Sometimes common knowledge isn't the truth.

Comment: @Orion Adrian: At least in plain old C (according to K&R), a++ increments a and yields the value before the increment, and ++a increments the value and yields the new value with the increment. I expect at least C++ to work the same way, but I'm not sure. So the example should be correct (if C# works the same way).

Comment: @Kimmo: The problem is in a++. DoStuff(a++) will do the increment immediately, but the result of the a++ function is the unincremented value. The above applies that DoStuff(a++) will not increment the a variable until after DoStuff is executed. See Frederik's or my answer for a more precise translation.

Comment: The point of ensuring that f(x++) is not equivalent to f(x); x = x + 1; is when you get to something like f(x++, x++) you're not going to think that you'll end up with f(x, x); x = x + 1; x = x + 1; Instead you're going to get temp = x; x = x + 1; temp2 = x; x = x + 1; f(temp, temp2);. That's why the following is a bad presumption. It also leads to "magical" thinking in that paramters can be modified after the call returns.

Answer (score 29):

Because the first example is really equivalent to:

```
public DoStuff(int level)
{  
  // ...
  int temp = level;
  level = level + 1;
  DoStuff(temp);
  // ...
}
```

Note that you can also write ++level; that would be equivalent to:

```
public DoStuff(int level)
{  
  // ...
  level = level + 1;
  DoStuff(level);
  // ...
}
```

It's best not to overuse the ++ and -- operators in my opinion; it quickly gets confusing and/or undefined what's really happening, and modern C++ compilers don't generate more efficient code with these operators anyway.

Comment: Agreed as to not overusing them. What is also 'great fun' is overloading post and pre ++ with a class as then all bets are off.

Comment: I have to disagree; `++` and `--` are extraordinarily intuitive and easy. The only time problems arise is when people either try to get cute or don't even bother to look up the behavior of the operators they're using.

Comment: So what's intuitive and easy about this? :-)

DoMoreStuff(++level, ++level);

Comment: I think that's classed as 'trying to get cute' :)

Comment: Additionally, his example is wrong. I'm not amazed how often people don't quite understand post-increment (variable++), but I see it wrong almost every time. Post-increment does not evaluate after the call. It evaluates before the call, specifically:

int temp = a;
a = a + 1;
DoStuff(temp);

Comment: That's a fairly subtle distinction for a local variable, though

Comment: The 2 are equivalent for the current example (apart from new temporary creation of course). More complicated examples would change this though.

Comment: I have to agree with Orion.
This answer demonstrates the point slightly but is missleading in terms of what actually happens.

Comment: It's one of those cases where it tends to teach people the wrong order of things (which goes wonky when people try to generalize). It also leads to the idea that the use of i++ increments after the for loop while ++i increments before the for loop; and other such craziness.

Comment: Your second code snippet isn't equivalent to the original question's though.  In the original question the level variable is never modified.  If it's used elsewhere (we don't know) then your way would produce different results.

Comment: OK, I've edited the example to be more correct. I do believe that this discussion shows exactly why you shouldn't overuse the pre/postincrement operators: there are subtle side effects that aren't obvious.

Comment: @Herms: It isn't supposed to be equivalent to the original question.

Comment: Even post editing, however, your example is still incorrect. There should be no code after the call to DoStuff, as all parameters are evaluated before the actual call to the function. To imply otherwise is incorrect.

Answer (score 27):

**level++** will pass **level** into **DoStuff** and then increment **level** for use in the rest of the function. This could be a fairly nasty bug as the recursion will never end (from what is shown **DoStuff** is always being passed the same value). Perhaps **++level** is meant instead, as this is the opposite of **level++** (increments level and passes the incremented value into **DoStuff**)?

**level+1** will pass **level+1** into **DoStuff** and leave **level** unchanged for the rest of the function.

Comment: ++level also produces a different behaviour. See the edits to my question.

Answer (score 12):

the return value of `level++` will be `level` and `therefore` pass `level` into `DoStuff`. This could be a fairly nasty bug as the recursion will never end (from what is shown `DoStuff` is always being passed with the same value). Perhaps `++level` or `level + 1` is meant instead?

`level + 1` will pass `level + 1` into `DoStuff` and leave `level` unchanged for the rest of the function.

---

The post-increment operator (variable++) is precisely equivalent to the function

```
int post_increment(ref int value)
{
    int temp = value;
    value = value + 1
    return temp;
}
```

while the pre-increment operator (++variable) is precisely equivalent to the function

```
int pre_increment(ref int value)
{
    value = value + 1;
    return value;
}
```

---

Therefore, if you expand the operator inline into the code, the operators are equivalent to:

```
DoStuff(a + 1)

int temp = a + 1;
DoStuff(temp);
```

---

```
DoStuff(++a)

a = a + 1;
DoStuff(a);
```

---

```
DoStuff(a++);

int temp = a;
a = a + 1;
DoStuff(temp);
```

---

It is important to note that post-increment is **not** equivalent to:

```
DoStuff(a);
a = a + 1;
```

---

Additionally, as a point of style, one shouldn't increment a value unless the intention is to use the incremented value (a specific version of the rule, "don't assign a value to a variable unless you plan on using that value"). If the value `i + 1` is never used again, then the preferred usage should be `DoStuff(i + 1)` and not `DoStuff(++i)`.

Comment: What you say is 100% true. But it is worth mentioning that for the post-increment version, the compiler is allowed to omit the temporary and relocate the inc till after usage for simple situations (such as using basic types).

Comment: Evan that's a kind of optimization that the compiler MIGHT make, but it also the kind of optimization that could cause very subtle problems.

Comment: It's also not an optimization that you can rely on. It's an implementation detail of the compiler and therefore isn't something that you should say definitely happens unless you're also willing to say that it happens in these versions of these compilers.

Comment: There's a mistake in your first code sample. temp is declared but never used.

Comment: Orion - Your level++ stack trace is incorrect. The first call to DoStuff places a value of 1 onto the stack. This is then modified to 2 before the second call occurs but after the value is placed on the stack for the next call.Your stack ends up being a series of 2s.

Comment: Orion - Your ++level stack is also incorrect. Similiar reasoning to my previous comment except the result is 5,4,3,2 (or 4,4,3,2 depending on where in the call you take the stack snap shot). This can be confirmed in VS2005 or VS2008.

Comment: I'm not exactly following you here. If you look at the level++ version, if the first call is DoStuff(1) then the next call (first recursive call) will be DoStuff(1) because the return value of 1++ is 1, not 2.

Answer (score 2):

The first is using the value in level and THEN incrmenting it.

The latter is using level+1 as a passed variable.

Answer (score 1):

`level++` returns the current value of `level`, then increments `level`.
`level+1` doesn't change `level` at all, but `DoStuff` is called with the value of `(level + 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public DoStuff(int level)
{

  // DoStuff(level);
  DoStuff(level++);
  // level = level + 1;
  // here, level's value is 1 greater than when it came in
}
```

It actually increments the value of level.

```
public DoStuff(int level)
{
  // int iTmp = level + 1;
  // DoStuff(iTmp);
  DoStuff(level+1);
  // here, level's value hasn't changed
}
```

doesn't actually increment the value of level.

Not a huge problem before the function call, but after the function call, the values will be different.

Comment: You got the first one the wrong way round: it will first call DoStuff(level) and afterwards increment level.

Comment: Woops.  Haha, hasty answer on my part :-p

Answer (score 1):

In level++ you are using postfix operator. This operator works after the variable is used. That is after it is put on the stack for the called function, it is incremented. On the other hand level + 1 is simple mathematical expression and it is evaluated and the result is passed to called function. 
If you want to increment the variable first and then pass it to called function, you can use prefix operator: ++level

Answer (score 0):

The first code snippet uses the post-operation increment operator, so the call is made as DoStuff(level);.  If you want to use an increment operator here, use DoStuff(++level);.

Answer (score 0):

level+1 sends whatever level+1 is to the function.
level++ sends level to the function and then increments it.

You could do ++level and that would likely give you the results you want.

Comment: ++level produces a different result. See the stack traces in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

The first example uses the value of 'index', increments the value and **updates** 'index'.

The second example uses the value of 'index' plus 1 but does not change the content of 'index'.

So, depending on what you are wanting to do here, there could be some surprises in store!

Comment: example uses 'level' not index. Suggest you edit this reply to follow?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it is tempting to rewrite as:

```
DoStuff(++level);
```

I personally think this is less readable than incrementing the variable prior to the method call. As noted by a couple of the answers above, the following would be clearer:

```
level++;
DoStuff(level);
```

Comment: The pre-increment and post-increment operators are meant to add a level of conciseness to code, not necessarily readability.  If you're shooting for readability, don't use this level of operator at all.  Use level = level + 1;

Comment: I didn't say it was more concise, just aids readability. I don't agree with using level = level + 1, as it involves more typing :) - I think most people know what ++ does, but (as per original question) sometimes get confused about the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a language that allows operator overloading, and '+ <integer>' has been defined to do something other than post- and prefix '++'.

Then again, I have only seen such abominations in school projects*, if you encounter that in the wild you probably have a really good, well-documented, reason.

[* a stack of integers, if I'm not mistaken. '++' and '--' pushed and popped, while '+' and '-' performed normal arithmetics]

Answer (score 0):

To put it in the most simple way, `++var` is a prefix operator and will increment the variables **before** the rest of the expression is evaluated. `var++`, a postfix operator, increments a variable **after** the rest of the expression is evaluated. And as others have mentioned of course, `var+1` creates just a temporary variable (seperate in memory) which is initiated with `var` and incremented with constant `1`.

Answer (score -2):

As far as my experience goes, the parameter expression is evaluated first, and gets a value of level. 
The variable itself is incremented before the function is called, because the compiler doesnt care whether you are using the expression as a parameter or otherwise... All it knows is that it should increment the value and get the old value as the result of the expression.

However in my opinion, code like this is really sloppy, since by trying to be clever, it makes you have to think twice about what is really happening.